# Referencing Table Headers in AdvancedFilter VBA Generated Table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that takes in some user input values to filter and copy the raw data to a sheet visible to the user.

```
Sheets("RawData").Range("Raw[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("RawData").Range("AH1:AL" & (i + 1)), _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("User").Range("A15"), Unique:=False
```

A table is generated from this newly copied data.

```
Sheets("User").Range("A15").CurrentRegion.Select
Set rng = Selection
Set tbl = Sheets("User").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "userSelections"
```

I have a table "Pareto" on another sheet that is looking to match if Events are happening on the same date:

```
=COUNTIFS(userSelections[MMM-YY], [Event Date])
```

However, when the macro regenerates "userTable" it recreates the headers and the formulas in "Pareto" lose their reference to "userTable" which causes this #REF error

```
=COUNTIFS(#REF!,[Event Date])
```

Turning calculation mode to manual did not work and deleting only the table contents using `DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete` or `DataBodyRange.ClearContents` did not work.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: @ARich How to keep the reference to userTable in the Countif formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way to keep the references, but found a workaround by inserting the formula after the table was recreated each time:

```
Sheets("RawData").Range("Raw[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("RawData").Range("AH1:AL" & (i + 1)), _
CopyToRange:=Sheets("User").Range("A15"), Unique:=False

Sheets("User").Range("A15").CurrentRegion.Select

Set rng = Selection
Set tbl = Sheets("User").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, xlYes)
    tbl.Name = "userSelections"

Sheets("Totals").ListObjects("tblTotal").ListColumns("Total Events").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF([RowNum] = """", """", COUNTIF(userSelections[MMM-YY], [Event Date]))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're deleting the table and recreating it every time. When you delete a table, any formulas that referenced that specific table will then have reference errors because that table doesn't exist anymore (even if the new table has the same name).

I would suggest deleting the table data and then inserting the new data into the existing table.

**Untested**

```
Sub main()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range

    'set the tbl variable to the existing table
    Set tbl = Sheets("User").ListObjects("userSelections")

    'delete the data from the existing table
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Delete

    'add the new data to the existing table
    'tbl.Range accesses the range the tbl covers
    'tbl.Range.Cells(1,1) references the first row and column (first cell) in the table range
    'tbl.Range.Cells(1,1).Offset(1,0) references the second row in the table, where your data will start
    Sheets("RawData").Range("Raw[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("RawData").Range("AH2:AL" & (i + 1)), _
    CopyToRange:=tbl.Range.Cells(1, 1).Offset(1, 0), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

This will copy the data to the table. The table will flex itself to encompass all the data, so there's really no need to create a new table each time.

Comment: This preserves the table but copies the headers of 'Raw' as row two of 'userSelections.' The correctly filtered raw data is copied over but as a range, not a table. So the table is always only two rows with both rows being duplicate headers.